# Showing a function $g(t) = \int_X f(x,t) d\mu$ is differentiable at $t=0$

Tags: real-analysis, limits, measure-theory, continuity

I am given the following question:

> Let $(X, \mathcal{M}, \mu)$ be a finite measure space, and let $f: X \times (-1,1) \to \mathbb{R}$ be a function such that for each $t \in (-1,1)$, $f(\cdot, t): X \to \mathbb{R}$ is $\mathcal{M}$-measurable, and such that for $\mu$.a.e. $x \in X$, $f(x, \cdot)$ has a classical derivative at $t=0$ in the sense that $$\frac{\partial f}{\partial t}(x,0) = \lim_{h \to 0^+}\frac{f(x,h)-f(x,0)}{h}$$
>   exists. Show that if there is $M < \infty$ such that $$|f(x,t) - f(x,0)| \leq M|t|$$
>   for $\mu$.a.e $x \in X$, then the function $g(t) = \int_X f(x,t) d\mu$ is differentiable at $t=0$ with $$g'(0) = \int_X \frac{\partial f}{\partial t}(x,0) d\mu$$

So, I think I'm trying to show that the following equality holds:

$$\lim_{h \to 0} \int_X \frac{f(x,h) - f(x,0)}{h} d\mu = \int_X \frac{\partial f}{\partial t}(x,0) d\mu$$

My limited experience tells me that perhaps this will simply be an application of dominated convergence, but I am a bit unsure of how to proceed. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let $h_n \to 0$

Then $|\frac{f(x,h_n)-f(x,0)}{h_n}|\leq M|h_n|\frac{1}{|h_n|}=M \in L^1(X)$ since we are in a space of finite measure.

So by Dominated Convergence theorem we have the conclusion.